# How to get the fragment values in an url using php

Tags: php, codeigniter, url

I have a link with a fragment idk how to get the values in url fragments....
My link is

http://localhost/i-net/admin/dashboard#access_token=eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsInR5cCIgOiAiSldUIiwia2lkIiA6ICJKbWVqYjdUcmJrWlo5UzFDSEhLS25oX0dhUThoTzlESE9WWktsWkFpczF3In0.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.GWgtB9_coCSA1MgTCvqQpX7-Hgtq5udDkN6CPdsdfdfdfWnnqJq3qI-S3g6K6J2NyjKC5xuUvkOo1qWV02q6_j1sgFGqpnmh6svjFJLExYP--P6m62WNl6m7oR3CKH-H4_uNamdPNdh3K1XwmoKGchBHRrXvanpko_15APpByPyA90ecStoi3IG3VKaM3odKiOxNs8LSfHwE67Hd-WxyA1JBfeMOgwWWeas9YTvrmB7vaalzMQqAHrNkKEF0OZ_WjN3GyX1TEOx1ZikFVAJdUExdiKC4pYpSVjnMv7BWaATd04DEsA9OAuF_ozgOpgFOxaseLvJQNIyar8XSTJJj45ioQmYcKA&token_type=Bearer&expires_in=900

Here I want to get the value of access_token, token_type and expires in datas.

Answer (score 2):

```
$url=parse_url("your url inside");
echo $url["fragment"]; //This variable contains the fragment
```